# Image too large and not rightly positioned in full width slider Wordpress Divi Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I am working on a website and so far I am satisfied with it's desktop view, but it has an issue on mobile and tablet view. The image in the full width slider is not displaying correctly. Is there a way to shrink the image in the mobile and tablet view only or is there a way to position the image so it fits to screen. The website is built with divi theme, wordpress. Thanks.

[The Website Url](https://www.thenextlevel.ng): www.thenextlevel.ng

Comment: They have a pretty good documentation. This [link](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-full-screen-slider-with-divi) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Divi theme full width slider the image should automatically adapt to the screen size if you add it in this way:

1. Add new full width section
2. Add full width slider
3. Open the settings for the full width slider
4. Under the "content" tab, at the top, click "add new slide"
5. Click "add media" and add the image and save.

If it still isn't adapting correctly to the screen size, you could try going into the full width slider settings and adjust the width of the image. When you move the width slider a little mobile phone icon will show up and you can adjust the width on mobile and tablet. If that does not work, you'd probably need to use some css.